# Select from table where row equal to option symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a table generated by a crud in symfony2. The entity is called "Voorraad"(=Stock) and is a table of 3 items: "aantal"(=number), "locatie_id"(location_id) and "product_id". Both the location id and product id are associations with another enitty (locatie entity and product entity). I try to order my stock by location but I cant get it right in symfony. I would like to have a option to select a location (id 1, id 2, id 3) and If a have selected a option it outputs the data of that location.

In mysql its the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `voorraad` WHERE `locatie_id` = 1
```

How can I achieve something like this in Symfony2/doctrine/twig?

My code:

View

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
<h1 class="hoofdtitel">Voorraad lijst</h1>
<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th>Id</th> -->
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Fabriek</th>
            <th>Aantal</th>
            <th>Inkoopprijs</th>
            <th>Verkoopprijs
            <th>Locatie</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
    <!--    <td><a href="{{ path('voorraad_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td> -->
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getNaam() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getType() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getFabric().getFabrieknaam() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.aantal }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getVerkoopprijs() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getLocatie().getLocatienaam() }}</td>
            <td>

                    <a href="{{ path('voorraad_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Voorraad aanpassen</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        {% if
                entity.aantal   == 1 %}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"> <p>Let op, voorraad van {{ entity.getProduct().getNaam() }} is 1 of minder </p></div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if
        entity.aantal   <= 0 %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <p>Let op, voorraad van {{ entity.getProduct().getNaam() }} is op </p></div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

        <br>
        <a href="{{ path('voorraad_new') }}">
            Nieuwe voorraad toevoegen   
        </a>

{% endblock %}
```

Controller

```
namespace ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Entity\Voorraad;
use ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Form\VoorraadType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * Voorraad controller.
 *
 * @Route("/voorraad")
 */
class VoorraadController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Voorraad entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="voorraad")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->findBy(array(), array('locatie'=>'asc'));

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
/**
 * Creates a new Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="voorraad_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Voorraad();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @param Voorraad $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Voorraad $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new VoorraadType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('voorraad_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="voorraad_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Voorraad();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="voorraad_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Voorraad entity.
*
* @param Voorraad $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Voorraad $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new VoorraadType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('voorraad_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Deletes a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Voorraad entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('voorraad_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Verwijder voorraad'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation maybe helps you :http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html. If your entity (Voorraad) has a relation with Locatie you can search by Locatie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use doctrine's findBy method :

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')
               ->findBy(['locatie'=>$locatieId]);
```

Comment: This one is better. I didn't know `findBy`  already exists so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method in your controller for this goal.An approximate code is as follows (but it all depends on your mapping info and attributes names).

```
public function getVoorraadByLocatieId($locatieId)
    {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT v
                FROM ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad v               
                WHERE v.locatie = :l_id'
                )->setParameter('l_id', $locatieId);
            $result = $query->getResult();

            return $result; 
    }
```

And in your action, do:

```
$this->getVoorraadByLocatieId($locatieId);
```

There are different ways of achieving the same result, like creating a service and calling it from inside controller (fat services with thin controllers is a god practice), or creating a custom Repository Class, but the idea is the same (the use of entity manager and doctrine fetching ). The advantage of latter ways is code organization/readability.

Comment: Best practice is to locate this method in related Repository class not in controller.

Comment: @fito, I totally agree with you. Glenn, please to google how to create Repository class and put the same logic inside

Comment: Thanks :), I have fixed my problem with this  `$entities = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad') ->findBy(['locatie'=>2]);` instead of using a variable I've hard coded the id's for each location, because creating my own controller/repository in symfony is new to me. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @GlennGijsberts, glad you are progressing. Step by step you will be expert in Symfony2/Doctrine2. Have a nice day